# GLSL 3.30 is not supported;Linking with uncompiled shader;OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

this code tells `GLSL 3.30 is not supported`

void GLSLShader::LoadFromString(GLenum type, const string& source) {
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader (type);

```
const char * ptmp = source.c_str();
glShaderSource (shader, 1, &ptmp, NULL);

//check whether the shader loads fine
GLint status;
glCompileShader (shader);
glGetShaderiv (shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
if (status == GL_FALSE) {
    GLint infoLogLength;        
    glGetShaderiv (shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    GLchar *infoLog= new GLchar[infoLogLength];
    glGetShaderInfoLog (shader, infoLogLength, NULL, infoLog);
    cerr<<"Compile log: "<<infoLog<<endl;
    delete [] infoLog;
}
_shaders[_totalShaders++]=shader;
```

}

this is the result of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.5.0-devel (git-6ee5eff 2015-01-28 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.0-devel (git-6ee5eff 2015-01-28 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.5.0-devel (git-6ee5eff 2015-01-28 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, C++ and QtCreator

and some part of the code tells `Linking with uncompiled shader`
How to enable GLSL3.0 or what else should I do?

Comment: Enabling glsl 3.0 can only be done by driver update if your gpu supports it. If your compilation failed because of the lack of GLSL 3.0 support, you get a follow-up error that you cannot link (since compile failed). If driver update doens't help, you can only eliminate GLSL3.0 calls in the shader and try to stick to a lower version of GLSL.

Comment: Also, check the versions that ARE supported with glGetString(GL_VERSION)) and glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)). If OpenGL version 3.3 isn't enabled, you won't be able to use GLSL 3.3.

Comment: From your glxinfo it looks like OpenGL and GLSL 3.3 (along with others) are supported.  Have you set a pixel format to specify what OpenGL version to use for your context?  For example my context defaults to OpenGL version 2.1.  I have GLSL shaders written in GLSL 4.1, so they won't compile in the default context.  I need to set a pixel format specifying OpenGL 4.1 to get the shaders to compile.

Comment: The glGetString commands will tell you what versions your context is using now.

Comment: @jwlaughton how to set a pixel format?the glGetString tells me using 3.0 Mesa 10.5.0 GLSL:1.30. But from glxinfo OpenGL and GLSL 3.3 are supported.How to enable GLSL3.3?

Comment: After I change the glutInitContextVersion (3, 3);It works

Comment: I haven't used glut, but I've looked a little at how glut deals with things that I would set in a pixel format.  Apparently glut deals with these setup issues with individual calls (like your glutInitContextVersion (3, 3) to set the version or glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA) to set double buffering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the OpenGL context when creating a a GL Widget using Qt like this:

```
QGLFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion( 3, 3 );
glFormat.setProfile( QGLFormat::CoreProfile );
glFormat.setSampleBuffers( true );

GLWidget w( glFormat );
```

Comment: But I'm using other people's code, create a GL widget does help.What could  I do to setProfile to CoreProfile with OpenGL?